# How can I get sum of count between two dates in sqlite

Tags: sql, sqlite, date, between

Datatype of date in table is DATE in us format i.e. 'mm-dd-yyyy'  I used `SELECT count from table_name Where Dt<'08/14/2020' AND Dt>'08/01/2020'`
Above will return a result with dates of year 2015. I want all count between 08/14/2020'and'08/01/2020 It seems It is comparing strings. please help me to solve this issue. I even tried between it also results the same.

Comment: Change the format of your dates to YYYY-MM-DD.

Comment: But I cant change in the deployment because we are having some offline installs. :-(((

Comment: is there a TO_CHAR function? you should be able to transform these dates into sortable order. is there a TO_DATE function? you should be able to convert your query values to dates -

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This worked for me, Thanks.

```
SELECT COUNT(*) AS Count FROM tab WHERE  DATE( SUBSTR( a.Dt,-4 )||'-'||Substr(a.Dt,1,2)||'-'||Substr(a.Dt,4,2) ) BETWEEN '2019-10-01' AND '2020-08-15';
```

Again this also works.

```
SELECT COUNT(*) AS Count FROM tab WHERE tab.date BETWEEN '20191001' AND '20200815';
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this - This should convert mm/dd/yyyy to yyyy-mm-dd. (Sqlite has one date format). After converting it, you should be able to filter using the where statement as dates instead of strings.

```
SELECT   substr(Date, 7) || "-" ||  substr(Date, 1,2) 
  || "-" || substr(Date,4,2) FROM Table
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use string operator `SUBSTR()`, and then convert to date format :

```
SELECT COUNT(*) AS Count
  FROM tab
 WHERE DATE( SUBSTR(dt,-4)||'-'||SUBSTR(dt,1,5) )
       BETWEEN '2020-08-01' AND '2020-08-14'
```

in order to get inclusive count for boundary date values.

<kbd>[Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlite_3.27&fiddle=37d4761ab109d909589814a73cce6236)</kbd>